# Can you give me an advice about MVC client-server?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, client-server

I'm going to create a desktop application (Swing) using the MVC. It will be chat and i have some questions. Which classes should be located on client? (View - its logical) Model? Controller? or both classes should be on the server side?
And which classes have to process my database?

Comment: I can give you some advice - don't create a desktop application with Java. Consider a web app, or native GUIs instead.

Comment: but i want. I like this

Comment: @user1886323 isn't totally right, but he isn't totally wrong either. Java is a great cross-platform language, but its GUI framework, Swing, is full of all sorts of intricacies and headaches that are probably beyond the scope of what you're wanting to learn on your first go. If you really decide you want to go the Swing route, I would start by reading *all* of the Java Swing tutorials (from Oracle). Good luck!

Comment: belongs at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev This question would be closed on Programmers as "too broad" for the same reasons it was here. It's basically asking us to design his entire app for him with almost no information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are planning to have server-client and database access, this sounds like a typical [3-tier distributed system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).

`Database` - represented as DBMS and located potentially on a separate machine. This should provide easy API for queries and updates from the `server`.

`Server` - this is where `Model` is located, again potentially on a different machine than `database`. `Server` however has means of working with the `database`, ideally via the aforementioned API.

`Client` - contains `View` and `Controller`. `View` is essentially the UI aspect of the `Model` located on the `server`. `Controller` processes user interaction and sends to the `server` in the processed (clean) form that the `server` can understand. This is done to reduce server load. The `client` has no means of accessing the `database` directly.

If it's all the same to you, I'd recommend to have a look at [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/best_practices/jfxpub-best_practices.htm), its MVC is much easier to implement and just plain simple to work with